# Error. Cannont convert from void to int

Tags: java

Recién me estoy iniciando con la POO y he echo un ejercicio para practicar los métodos y las  variables estàticas,la idea del ejercicio es imitar al método estàtico pow de la classe math , pero tengo el siguiente error Cannont convert from void to int.

```
public class Matematicas {

    private static int base;

    private static int exponente;

    private static int resultado;

    public Matematicas () {


    }

    public static void pow ( int base, int exponente) {


        Matematicas.base = base;

        Matematicas.exponente = exponente;

        for (int i = 0; i < exponente; i++) {

            resultado = Matematicas.base * Matematicas.base;



        }

    }
}
```

Aquí esta el error:

```
public class MisMatematicas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int elevado = Matematicas.pow(2, 2);

    }

}
```

¿A que se debe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto a el error que obtienes:

> Cannont convert from void to int

En esta caso se debe a que estas esperando obtener un valor tipo `int` pero estas en realidad obteniendo un valor `void`.

El método `pow()` lo definiste que retorne un valor `void`, y debe retornar de acuerdo a tu código un valor entero (`int`):

```
//public static void pow ( int base, int exponente) {

public static int pow ( int base, int exponente) {
```

por lo tanto realiza el cambio para que retorne un valor entero (int) en tu método para que puedas usarlo en tus operaciones.

No olvides agregar el valor de retorno usando `return`:

```
public static int pow ( int base, int exponente) {


    Matematicas.base = base;

    Matematicas.exponente = exponente;

    for (int i = 0; i < exponente; i++) {

        resultado = Matematicas.base * Matematicas.base;       

    }

    return resultado;

}
```

Revisa lo siguiente:

[**Métodos en Java, funciones y procedimientos. Cómo hacerlos y usarlos**](https://www.programarya.com/Cursos/Java/Funciones)

**[Devolver un valor de un método](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html) (inglés)**

Comment: Muchas Grácias, quedria preguntar otra cosa, ¿ esto que estas haciendo es como hacer  un setter y un getter a la vez no ?

Comment: Ahí se aplica el concepto de valor de retorno, si! @CarlosPerandelBrio generalmente un getter se define con un valor de retorno y un setter como void ya que no esperas obtener un valor si no definirlo.

Answer (score 2):

El error se debe a que la declaración del método "pow" esta mal....tu tienes algo asi:

```
public static void pow ( int base, int exponente)
```

Si declaras este método así le estas diciendo a Java que no devuelve ningún valor ese método, y eso es falso, devuelve el valor entero de la operación que realiza. Por tanto tu método "pow" debería ser algo así:

```
public static int pow ( int base, int exponente)
```

Y retornar el valor entero que te de al hacer la potencia de un numero sobre el otro. Al hacer la declaración del método correctamente te quitas de una el fallo que te da ya que ambos argumentos serán del tipo int.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que retornar un int en tu metodo `pow`:

```java
public static int pow ( int base, int exponente) {
    Matematicas.base = base;
    Matematicas.exponente = exponente;

    int resultado = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < exponente; i++) {
        resultado = resultado * Matematicas.base;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Otra cosa, no necesitas declarar las variables estaticas que estas utilizando (`base`, `exponente`), puedes utilizar directamente las que estan en los argumentos:

```
public static int pow(int base, int exponente) {
    // TODO: Operaciones con exponente igual a 0
    // TODO: Operaciones con exponente negativos
    // TODO: Operaciones con exponente decimales

    int resultado = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < exponente; i++) {
        resultado = resultado * base;
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Si ves el codigo aunque no estes usando las variables estaticas si estas declarando una funcion estatica.

Nota: No puedes asignar un `void` a una variable `int`.